# Uninstall older version of the application

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

I have installer generated by WiX and I want it to ask: "You have already installed this app. Do you want to uninstall it?" when run. Currently it installs the app once more and uninstalls it incorrectly if there was another version installed before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The folowing will allow you to perform an upgrade, which removes previous versions:

```
<?define Version = "!(bind.fileVersion.<YOUR-FILE-HERE>)" ?>
<?define UpgradeCode = "<YOUR-GUID-HERE>" ?>

<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.Version)" IncludeMinimum="no" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED" />
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0" Maximum="$(var.Version)" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="yes" Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED" />
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize" />
  <Custom Action="NewerVersion" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWERVERSIONDETECTED</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="NewerVersion" Error="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
```

You will need to define UpgradeCode and Version to suit your needs, this will also allow you to perfom an upgrade even if the version hasn't changed.

Comment: Yes, it would be good to ask to uninstall anyway, whether an older or this version is already installed

Comment: Do you mean you would like to prompt before an upgrade, rather than just detect and remove previous versions?

Comment: No, I don't want to upgrade at all, I want it to say: "You have already installed this app. Do you want to uninstall it?", and I want it to say it anyway, whether it is already installed older or current version. Thank you

Comment: Old Version Installed = Prompt for uninstall, then only uninstall. Current Version Installed = Prompt for uninstall, then only uninstall. So if it's already installed you only want to prompt to uninstall?

Comment: A user-friendly installer would either support side-by-side installation of several versions or perform upgrade to a newer version. You can ask users if they want to upgrade before performing upgrade. If they don't want to, don't install newer version. You can't conditionally schedule uninstall of an *unrelated* product with MSI.

Comment: I tried putting your markup inside my `<Product>`, but I'm getting an error: *Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.UpgradeCode)'* Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, my approach is to store both the version and Upgrade code as preprocessor variables, I'll update the example.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't seem to work at all, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @szx see answer by jbudreau who points at more modern approaches to this situation.

Comment: @DavidMartin: I've read about MajorUpgrade but unfortunately that's not quite what I want. I'd like to show a custom dialog that would ask the user whether they want to uninstall existing version if found, and exit if they say no.

Comment: @szx I suggest the best thing to do is to create a new question showing what you have tried, where it is going wrong and the desired outcome, comments aren't really the right medium for this.

Comment: @idm have you work this out? I want that dialog too with the same queston.

Answer (score 7):

If you use WiX 3.5 you have the [MajorUpgrade](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/major_upgrade.htm) element at your disposal.